# Bing maps silverlight control in c#

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, bing-maps

Wondering if you could help me on this one.. Im trying to control my map with this c# code below. But for some reason its not doing anything when I call this method, and im not quite sure why?! Not sure if im using the .Equals properly?

C#

```
private void NW_zoom(object sender, ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        GeoCoordinate abc = new GeoCoordinate(51.510, -0.1151);
        Map.CenterProperty.Equals(abc);

        var zoom = 12;
        Map.ZoomLevelProperty.Equals(zoom);
     }
```

XMAL map control:

```
 <maps:Map ZoomLevel="10" Mode="Road" Margin="0,0,0,54"   ZoomBarVisibility="Visible" ScaleVisibility="Visible" CredentialsProvider="xxxxxxx" Grid.Row="1">
       <maps:Map.Center>
            <device:GeoCoordinate Latitude="51.510669" Longitude="-0.11512800"/>
        </maps:Map.Center> 
        <maps:MapLayer  x:Name="QuakeLayer" Height="726" Width="477" /> 
    </maps:Map>
```

Comment: What outcome are you expecting? are you trying to set the map centre and zoom level?

Answer (score 1):

`Equals` compares values, it does not set them.

Try

```
Map.CenterProperty = abc;
```

and

```
Map.ZoomLevelProperty = zoom;
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the Equals word :-) Unfortunately as siad above the = proves problematic too :-(.

Answer (score 1):

Not having worked with this control I can't answer your question for sure but

```
Map.CenterProperty.Equals(abc);
```

only performs a boolean comparison, I'm pretty sure you want to set some property instead as in

```
Map.CenterPropert= abc;
```

(same goes for the other property)

Comment: Thank you, but its not happy with the = hence why I was trying other methods :(. I get these errors with the line:
A static readonly field cannot be assigned to (except in a static constructor or a variable initializer). 
And:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Windows.DependencyProperty'

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking to accomplish is done by the following:

```
Map.SetView(new Location(51.510, -0.1151), 12);
```

Edit --

You were correct, the code above is not supported for the WP7 bing Map control

this should work for you:

```
map1.SetView(new System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate(51.510, -0.1151), 12.00);
```

Comment: Thanks Blounty. Not quite there for some reason. This is using Windows phone 7 if it makes a difference. The errors I get with this line is:
 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.Platform.Location' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments 
, and:
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.Core.MapBase.SetView(System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate, double)'

Answer (score 0):

ZoomLevelProperty is a property, so if you want to set it in code behind, you need to use the method SetValue of the map object.

```
map.SetView(Map.ZoomLevelProperty, zoom);
```